# Use authentication token of Django in backend

Tags: python, django, authentication, token

i sent a Get request to my django backend with a Token authentication. After the authentication was succesful, I want to use the provided Token in my backend.

I already know how to check if it is a Token authentication by this piece of code:

```
if isinstance(request.auth, obd_data.token.UserIDToken):
    #Here I want to get the token for further processing
```

In debug mode, I already checked the whole request object and tried to find the token in there. But there is none.
Is it somehow possible to get this token? Or is it not designated to get the Token in plain text?

Thank you in forward.

Comment: Is the token in the querystring as a named segment? or a parameter?

Comment: I just set it in my Postman as a header entry like this Authorization: Token safsdfhqffiuhfuhawliufhwle

Comment: Ah. Look in the `request.META` dictionary for the header.